# Image does not go with Content Mode

Tags: swift, xcode

When I set imageView image in xib storyboard, image displays normally, but when I set image programmatically, it shows like this:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHpQc.png)

Here is the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AppCellID", for: indexPath) as! AppTableViewCell
    cell.nameOfAppLabel.text! = "Name"
    cell.descOfAppLabel.text! = "Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description "
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder-iosicon")
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What do you set it to be in the storyboard? Fill?

Comment: @barbarity in storyboard I set content mode and image to display

Comment: but do you set it to Scale to Fill? Could you also put how it should look like?

Comment: @barbarity yes it is, it should look like this https://prnt.sc/q1etw5

Comment: Did you also set the constraints programmatically? It looks like the root of the problem

Comment: @barbarity I set content mode (but even without setting it in code image doesn't show properly) and image to display

Comment: Are you setting the cell's imageView in the table's datasource method cellFoRow(at:), dequeueing and returning the cell there? Would you be able to share that code?

Comment: @Wattholm I updated question with full code of cellRowAt